# Can a MD5 implementation be optimized if all message are known to be of a certain fixed length and with certain bytes known?

Tags: c, assembly, optimization, cryptography, md5

Quite self explanatory question.
I have a set of messages, each with same known data in certain byte offsets.

Example:

```
bytes 1 to 32 -> is always the value 42
bytes 128 to 156 -> is always the value 128
```

But every other byte is different for different messages.

And let's say each message is 256 byte long.

With constraints (or similar constraints) like the above, can the MD5 implementation (in C say) for every message be optimized? Any pointers on the algorithm on how to go about it would help.

Comment: @hemagicalyang You may do anything that you like.

Comment: Probably it can. Look at the MD5 code. But you should check if it's really worth the hassle.

Comment: Could you shorten the message and keep only the first 42 and 128?

Comment: @JackLilhammers No. It's not an option. The md5 needs to be appended to every message at the end.

Comment: If you controlled both the side that computes the md5 and the one that checks it, you could compute it on the shortened version and then append it to the original one. Otherwise you've got to really study the algorithm and more than one implementation, but it could take a lot of time...

Comment: Similar applies here. [Optimizing SHA-256 implementation for fixed input prefix](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88257/18298)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an existing highly-optimized MD5 implementation (e.g. using SSE for x86), you could modify it.

You could pre-compute the state after handling the first 32 bytes and just start from there every time, loading those constants instead of computing them.  That would shave off two 128-bit chunks of work.  MD5 internally [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Algorithm) uses 128-bit (16-byte) state, but handles the message in chunks of 512 bits (64 bytes).  So you actually only know *half* of the first chunk of the message :/

But if I'm reading the pseudocode correctly, only the first half of the first round involves only data from the first 32 bytes with itself, so that's as much as you can pre-compute.  (The `if 0 ≤ i ≤ 15 then` ... `g := i` part: g = 0..7 is the low eight 32-bit words, i.e. the first 32 bytes).

But after that, unknown data (from the 3rd and 4th 16-byte) starts to get mixed in (XORed and so on), and after that there's not going any easy savings, and probably none even possible.  XOR on normal CPUs is not faster when one input is a known constant.  (In *hardware* yes, it's a NOT or a wire depending on the constant.)  If the data was known to be *zero* (or maybe all-ones), that might be different.

**So bottom line, you could probably save a few % from the total time for a 256-byte message by operating this way, saving part of 1 round (of 4) for the first of 4 blocks for the message.**  To compete with asm or SIMD intrinsics optimized implementations, you'd need to use their same implementation techniques, just start with loading some constants and jumping to a point half way through the first round.

---

Since this looks like a hypothetical, **if you knew the first 64 bytes,** you could skip all the "rounds" for processing those bytes and just start on the 2nd 64 bytes with a pre-computed 128-bit state.

Also note that a message length of 248 bytes would be (significantly?) faster, because MD5 pads the message to have room to append the 64-bit (8-byte) message length and still be a multiple of 64 bytes.  So message lengths > 248 have to do another whole set of 4 rounds with mostly zeros.

---

The 128..156 range being known does not, I think, help.  There's unknown data before it, and all the operations of each round of MD5 depends on the previous internal state.  Remember that MD5 was designed to be a cryptographically secure hash.  (It's now known not to be as secure as we'd like for its bit-length, but I don't think the weaknesses that have been discovered will be much if any help - it's still fast to compute it forwards.)

It's probably not even worth special-casing those known bytes in the middle; just do them as part of your loop over the rest of the buffer.  All you could save would be the initial load of the data, but it's less than a whole cache line so you wouldn't even avoid touching that line.

It's not worth the extra branching to get out of the loop.

Comment: Yes, your reading is correct. And it complicates the coding and even it can make it slower. A better idea is to compress the first 32-byte with padding then use the result as the IV for MD5' that I've suggested in [crptography.se](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/88257/18298) that you may already know.